# UIScrollView animate offset change when removing nested view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a stack view - I'm basically replicating a tabs feature.

One tab has a taller view than the other, so when I hide the view in the stack view it resizes.

This causes the scroll view to jump to the offset that fits the shorter view, in the event the user has scrolled to the top.

[image]

Is it possible to instead animate this change? Instead of the jump, the view scrolls to the correct offset? I am unsure how to achieve this.

```
final class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

  private var visibleTab: TabState = .overview {
    didSet {
      guard oldValue != visibleTab else { return }
      switch visibleTab {
        case .overview:
          self.spacesTab.isHidden = true
          self.overviewTab.isHidden = false
        case .spaces:
          self.spacesTab.isHidden = false
          self.overviewTab.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }

  enum TabState {
    case overview
    case spaces
  }

  private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.delegate = self
    view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    return view
  }()

  private let contentStackView: UIStackView = {
    let view = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.axis = .vertical
    view.alignment = .fill
    view.spacing = 8
    view.distribution = .fill
    return view
  }()

  private let tabSelectorView: UIStackView = {
    let view = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    view.axis = .horizontal
    view.distribution = .fillEqually
    return view
  }()

  private let overviewTab: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    view.isHidden = false
    return view
  }()

  private let spacesTab: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 780).isActive = true
    view.isHidden = true
    return view
  }()

  private let profileHeader = ScrollViewProfileHeaderView(frame: .zero)

  private lazy var overviewTabButton = makeButton(title: "Overview")
  private lazy var spacesTabButton = makeButton(title: "Spaces")

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureUI()
  }

}

extension ScrollViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate { }

private extension ScrollViewController {
  func configureUI() {
    overviewTabButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showOverviewTab), for: .touchUpInside)
    spacesTabButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSpacesTab), for: .touchUpInside)

    [overviewTabButton, spacesTabButton].forEach(tabSelectorView.addArrangedSubview)

    profileHeader.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tabSelectorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    [overviewTab, spacesTab].forEach(contentStackView.addArrangedSubview)

    [profileHeader, tabSelectorView, contentStackView].forEach(scrollView.addSubview(_:))
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

      profileHeader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
      profileHeader.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
      profileHeader.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),

      tabSelectorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeader.bottomAnchor),
      tabSelectorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
      tabSelectorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),

      contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
      contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
      contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabSelectorView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
      contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
      contentStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
    ])
  }

  func makeButton(title: String) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return button
  }

  @objc func showOverviewTab() {
    visibleTab = .overview
  }

  @objc func showSpacesTab() {
    visibleTab = .spaces
  }
}

final class ScrollViewProfileHeaderView: UIView {

  private let headerImage: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    return view
  }()

  private let profileCard: ProfileCardView = {
    let view = ProfileCardView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .purple
    return view
  }()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .white

    [headerImage, profileCard].forEach(addSubview(_:))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      headerImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
      headerImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
      headerImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
      headerImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),

      profileCard.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerImage.centerYAnchor),
      profileCard.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 48),
      profileCard.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
      profileCard.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -48),
      profileCard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 270),
    ])
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to make some additional changes, but this might get you on your way.

In your `visibleTab` / `didSet` block, use `UIView.animate()` when you hide the `spacesTab`:

```
private var visibleTab: TabState = .overview {
    didSet {
        guard oldValue != visibleTab else { return }
        switch self.visibleTab {
        case .overview:
            // set duration longer, such as 1.0, to clearly see the animation...
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.spacesTab.isHidden = true
                self.overviewTab.isHidden = false
            }
        case .spaces:
            self.spacesTab.isHidden = false
            self.overviewTab.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```